# Costs of enabling versioning in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cost-management

I have a question about the costs of versioning in Amazon S3 that don't seem to be present in the guide.  There is a cost for every PUT/POST, but for versioned objects(especially when you keep older versions in alternative storage such as glacier) does each PUT/POST cost 2x the PUT/POST cost, one for the new version then one to move the old version to glacier?

Answer (score 33):

You can refer to FAQ page: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/?nc1=h_ls

> Q: How am I charged for using Versioning?
>
> Normal Amazon S3 rates apply for every version of an object stored or
>   requested. For example, let’s look at the following scenario to
>   illustrate storage costs when utilizing Versioning (let’s assume the
>   current month is 31 days long):
>
> 1) Day 1 of the month: You perform a PUT of 4 GB (4,294,967,296 bytes)
>   on your bucket. 2) Day 16 of the month: You perform a PUT of 5 GB
>   (5,368,709,120 bytes) within the same bucket using the same key as the
>   original PUT on Day 1.
>
> When analyzing the storage costs of the above operations, please note
>   that the 4 GB object from Day 1 is not deleted from the bucket when
>   the 5 GB object is written on Day 15. Instead, the 4 GB object is
>   preserved as an older version and the 5 GB object becomes the most
>   recently written version of the object within your bucket. At the end
>   of the month:
>
> Total Byte-Hour usage [4,294,967,296 bytes x 31 days x (24 hours /
>   day)] + [5,368,709,120 bytes x 16 days x (24 hours / day)] =
>   5,257,039,970,304 Byte-Hours.
>
> Conversion to Total GB-Months 5,257,039,970,304 Byte-Hours x (1 GB /
>   1,073,741,824 bytes) x (1 month / 744 hours) = 6.581 GB-Month
>
> The fee is calculated based on the current rates for your region on
>   the Amazon S3 Pricing page.